# R regex escape not working with variable names

Tags: regex, r, escaping

I'm trying to select columns in a data frame in R based on the column name. I want columns where the column name either contain "activity", "subject" or "originaldataset", or end with "mean()" or "std()". When I do

```
colselection <- grep('mean\\(\\)$|std\\(\\)$|subject|activity|originaldataset',
                     colnames(completedf))
selectdf <- completedf[,colselection]
```

I only get columns with "activity", "subject" or "originaldataset", none ending with "mean()" or "std()". Note: "completedf" is the original complete data frame.

Examples of column names: *tBodyAccMag-mean(), tBodyAccMag-std(),   tBodyAccJerkMag-mean(), tBodyAccJerkMag-std()*. The names are read from a text file with `read.table` and the column with the names are placed in a character vector that is later used for the column names in the data frame "completedf".

I am running R Studio Version 0.99.902 with R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: You are escaping the `$`, which is not needed i.e. `grep('mean\\(\\)$|std\\(\\)$|subject|activity|originaldataset', colnames(completedf))`

Comment: In `R`, we need \\ and not single \.

Comment: If I do `code'grep('mean\\(\\)$', colnames(completedf), value = TRUE)`, I get an empty character vector. I also get an empty character vector without the $. Weird.

Comment: Also get an empty result with `grep('mean[:punct:]$', colnames(completedf), value = TRUE)`

Comment: You didn't show the column names, so we don't know what you have there.

Comment: Edited post to show examples of column names and also to correct the escape of $.

Comment: Based on the example you provided all of the elements are matching `grep("(activity|subject|originaldataset)|(mean\\(\\)|std\\(\\))$", v1, value = TRUE)
#[1] "tBodyAccMag-mean()"     "tBodyAccMag-std()"      "tBodyAccJerkMag-mean()" "tBodyAccJerkMag-std()" `

Comment: @ElToro1966: It looks that the latest edit contains working code, right?

Comment: Nope. `v1 = colnames(completedf); grep("(activity|subject|originaldataset)|(mean\\(\\)|std\\(\\))$", v1, value = TRUE)
[1] "subject"         "activity"        "originaldataset"` Can this have something to do with the encoding of the text file not being the same as the R environment?

Comment: `file -bi features.txt` gives `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`, while the environment is `en-US.UTF-8` (from `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out thanks to participants in a R-course I am currently following.

**Column names can't contain parenthesis in R, so R replaces parenthesis with punctuation marks.**

For instance:

*fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag.std()*

becomes

*fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag.std..*

and so on. That is why the regex with punctuation marks works, while the one with parenthesis doesn't.